# "half of a million" vs. "half a million"

Tags: word-usage

Image a company that earned 500,000 dollars last year.

Some guys are talking about that company in a bar.

> That company earned **half a million** dollars last year.

Some news paper would also "half a million" when reporting that company.

What I'm trying to say is that, it seems that people use "half of a million" both in informal situation (casual talk) and formal situation(news report).

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/half) gives these examples

> half a dozen
>
> Roughly half (of) the class are Spanish and the others are a mixture of nationalities.

which seems to indicate that the "of" is unnecessary when "half" precedes a number.

However, [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=half%20of%20a%20million%2C%20half%20a%20million&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chalf%20of%20a%20million%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Chalf%20a%20million%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhalf%20a%20million%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHalf%20a%20million%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Chalf%20of%20a%20million%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Chalf%20a%20million%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhalf%20a%20million%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHalf%20a%20million%3B%2Cc0) shows that people might use "**half of** a million" sometimes.

the question is that, in what kind of situation, people use "half of a million". Could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you click the date ranges below the graph in your ngram link, you can see examples of the usages Google found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use **one half of** in sentences like:

> **One half of** the population of this country are rich.

And, **half a** in sentences like:

> **Half a minute ago...**
>
> **Half a million dollars...** etc.

If you are looking for a rule the rule will be like this:

> We normally use **"half a"** before **units of measurement.**

But **exceptions** abound.

Hope that helped.

Comment: Thank you. Are "One half of the population" and "half (of) the class" the same usage?

Comment: @WXJ96163 the most natural will be: "one half of the class". By the way you can upvote the answer if it helped.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive explanation. Would you please name some exceptions about that rule?